# Sylius : 404 Not found on media products

Tags: image, file-upload, media, sylius

I've a problem with the latest version of `Sylius`. When I try to upload an image for a product, the picture appears in the folders `public/media/image` but not in the website.

When I examinate it with chrome console, I see:

> Not Found, The requested resource /media/cache/resolve/sylius_small/95/39/fa0110f42bcb91fc99e4b2012bc4.jpeg was not found on this server.

Do someone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you using a web server? If so, then what's the configuration for the site?

Comment: Hello, it's just a PHP 7.3.8 Development Server.

Comment: Do you have the php-gd extension installed and enabled? Because if the image appears in `public/media/image` but it does not appear in `public/media/cache`, it's because LiipImagineBundle (responsible of generating those cache images) is not doing its job somehow. It's my only guess. EDIT: now that I think about it, it could be also a permission problem. Make sure that `public/media/cache` is writable by the server user.